# how to read each row and insert into database along with remove unwant white space as well as multiple comma

Tags: node.js, csv, express

i've gone through csv-parser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse) document but haven't been able to find any solution, also i've read all read me but still haven't found any solution related to this situatuion

```
    [ Row {
    bankcustomers_id: '154491',
    customerid: '   154491',
    title: 'MR         ',
    firstname: 'Santa ',
    lastname: 'Clause ',
    dob: '25-Dec-30',
    mobileno: '07900 1234567 ',
    emailid: 'santa-clause@northpole   ',

    ' }]
```

above is the output of product by csv parser now my problem is that is there any provision to remove this white space at start and last of charater or consecutive ,,. And how i can get single column value. How i can remove all mention this is there anybody help me out with this

moreover i want to insert each row into data base so how i can read row on this function

```
    .on('data', (data) =>{
    // console.log(data)
    results.push(data)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the ltrim and rtrim options? These will trim whitespace at either end of each field (if the field is not quoted)

```
const parse = require('csv-parse')

const input = `bankcustomers_id,customerid,title,firstname,lastname,dob,mobileno,emailid
154491,   154491,MR         ,Santa ,Clause ,25-Dec-30,07900 1234567 ,santa-clause@northpole   `;

const options = { delimiter: ",", cast: true, columns: true, ltrim: true, rtrim: true};

parse(input, options, function(err, output){
    console.log(output);
});
```

The output I get is:

```
[ { bankcustomers_id: 154491,
    customerid: 154491,
    title: 'MR',
    firstname: 'Santa',
    lastname: 'Clause',
    dob: '25-Dec-30',
    mobileno: '07900 1234567',
    emailid: 'santa-clause@northpole' 
} ]
```

Comment: thanks for you reply I will try it on next day . I have one more concerned will this parser handle lakhs of record if yes what configuration I required to do

Comment: Cool,  by lack of records,  do you mean empty records? Like ,,,,,,?

Comment: thanks for help my question is .will this parser  handle huge CSV file .if yes what extra things require to do

Comment: This parser will definitely handle large CSV files, it is used for this purpose by a lot of people! The stream API will ensure scalability, see the docs at https://csv.js.org/parse/api/.